# Nginx 404 rewrite issue

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm trying to grab variables between slashes and pass them to my management script with the following rewrite line in Nginx:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5&p6=$6;
```

If I request the page with less than 6 variables (eg: /var1/var2/var3/var4/var5/) it 404s.

Is it possible to use this with less than 6 variables? (I will need the full 6 variables in different parts of my web application though)

Running CentOS 6 in OpenVZ with Nginx 1.4.1-1.el6 64bit + PHP-FPM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have exactly six items between slashes, then this pattern won't match, and you'll get a 404.

You can make five new rewrite rules containing one through five variables, respectively, (or someone who's better at regex than I am might suggest a single rule to cover all six cases, but that's above most people's heads) or just handle this in your application instead.